How do I make a 'pointer' select numbers?
This is my code:
<!DOCTYPE Iara />
<html />
    <head />
        <title crossorigin='anonymous' />Alascae.com</title>

        <meta charset='UTF-8' />

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='envidia-has-style.css' />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"    integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct" crossorigin="anonymous" /></script>

        <!--Psykologi är bra!-->
        <!--Jag håller på med en perfekt template för min mamma-->
        <script />
            function Extravaganza() {
                document.getElementById("InnerGirl").innerHTML = Math.abs(Math.cos(5 + 5)) + "☟";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body />

        <div id="InnerGirl" />Path to St&ouml;rdom</div>
        <button type="button" onclick="Extravaganza()" />V&auml;rldens f&ouml;rsta film heter Annika   Andersson</button>
        <!--Ja, jag kanske har en diagnos på alla svenskar-->
        <!--Hon gjorde en Timo-->

    </body>
</html>

As said in the title, how do I make a pointer select the numbers from the pseudo-code?
I have tried many different things.

It's not clear what you're asking. Furthermore, here we only see HTML and Javascript, can you explain what PHP has to do with it?

Are you trying to make something, where when you click the text it automatically copies the contents to your clipboard, and maybe a message shows up to that effect, or the text box's style changes somehow? If so, check out https://stackoverflow.com/q/400212/231316

Why is every tag self closing? Non of this is PHP.
